# writing data frames into multiple excel file

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr

I have data frame in following form:

```
    name_1 name_2 col_1 col_2 col_3
 [1,] a     d      1     4     7  
 [2,] b     e      2     5     8  
 [3,] c     f      3     6     9
```

I want to select column name_2 with each of the column 1,2 and 3 and write them into one excel file in 3 different sheets.

In other words I would like to have columns "name_2" and "col_1" in first sheet of my excel file and columns "name_2" and "col_2" in second sheet and columns "name_2" and "col_3" in third sheet.

I am using this for loop as following

```
for(i in 2:5){
  df <- data.frame(my file)
  df <- df[,c(2,i+1)]
  write.xlsx(x = df, file = "/pathtofolder/excel.xlsx", sheetName = "column_name",append=TRUE, row.names = T, col.names = T)
}
```

But the final excel file is over written with the last df.

Do you have any idea how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook("/pathtofolder/excel.xlsx")

for(i in 2:4){
  addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = colnames(df)[i+1])
  writeData(wb = wb, sheet = colnames(df)[i+1], x = df[,c(2,i+1)], colNames = F)
}

saveWorkbook(wb,"/pathtofolder/excel.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

If the Excel file already exists use `loadWorkbook` instead of `createWorkbook`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could create the excel sheets with your code. There is on problem in my real data.The name of columns are more than 31 characters and it complains the the sheet name cannot be larger than 31 character. It is ok if the name of sheets are something like sheet1, sheet2 and etc. Can you help me with this one as well. Thanks

Comment: You could create a vector of names to use as Sheet names. ( `sheetNames = c("Sheet1", "Sheet2",..etc)` and then reference them by replacing `colnames(df)[i+1]` with `sheetNames[i-1]` (i-1 since i starts at 2.

Comment: You can also generate the names using `sheetNames = paste0("Sheet",1:10)`